# Javascript, difference in processing a string and string in a variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use styled-notification, a javascript library to manage popup notifications, but I do not think this issue is specific to this library.

I create an error notification using:

```
const error_notification = window.createNotification({
    closeOnClick: true,
    displayCloseButton: false,
    positionClass: 'nfc-top-right',
    showDuration: 3500,
    theme: 'error'
});
```

Then I call it with:

```
error_notification({
    title: 'Unsuccesful login',
    message: result.data.log
});
```

Where `result` is an object returned as json by the server and its member `result.data.log` is a string. However, only the `title` field is displayed, not the `message`. Now, if I replace `message` with a string:

```
error_notification({
    title: 'Unsuccesful login',
    message: "my message"
});
```

the message is displayed.

Could there be a difference in type between `result.data.log` and "my message" that could explain the difference in processing ?

Comment: First thing to do is verify that `result.data.log` is actually what you think it is. A string is a string.

Comment: `result`, `result.data` or `result.data.log` might not have the values you think they have. As Pointy said, a string is a string. A variable/property is just a container for a value. Whether you provide a string value directly or whether you pull it out of a container first doesn't make a difference. The object will never know where the value of its `message` property came from.

Comment: Well, result.data.log was an array of strings... Now I now how to use console.log... Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

`result.data.log` was an array of strings: `console.log` provided the type information.